# Angular 4 Property get binding does not show anything

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have following code

```
export class TestClass{
    private time: string = "Test";

    public get TimeFormatted(): string {
        return this.time;
    }
}
```

and in my template

```
   <span>{{item.TimeFormatted}}</span>
```

but nothing shows up in the html.

Comment: you're using this model for some data you recieved from your server?

Comment: Please add runnable sample

Comment: Yes I am using it so I can format it as I want it. But apart from this even If I didnt above code shouldn't be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess your just mapping the models in your Request like the following.

```
let Array<TestClass> arr = response.json();
```

If so this won't affect any Methods that are implemented in your Model.
To use your Model Methods you need to initiate a new Object from your Class and map its Attributes. If you initiate a Model in TS the functions will be added correctly, if your just parsing it form your request the Attributes will be accessible like normally but your Methods won't be added because your Object is not initiated, it's just parsed.

```
const newArr = new Array<TestClass>();
arr.foreach(item =>{
  let newItem = new TestClass();
  //mapping stuff 
  newArr.push(newItem);
});
```

Comment: Thank you didn't know that it was working like this.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use getters and setters, try the below code. every time you change the time, setter function will be called and you can use any condition over it. You can also see the working version here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-getters-setters

TS file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public _time: string;
  public password : string;


  constructor() {
    this._time="Test";
    this.password="password";

  }


    public get time(): string {
        return this._time;
    }

    public set time(value) {
      alert("set");
      if(this.password==="password"){
    this._time = value+"verified";
      }
  }

}
```

HTML code

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="time" />
```